# Can't find .bib files after upgrade to OS X Yosemite

Tags: bibtex, texshop, mactex

I've upgraded to Yosemite and TeXShop now can't find bib files which I previously had in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib`

The bib files are now in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib`

Works fine if the .bib file is in the same folder as the .tex, but I prefer to keep all my .bib files together.

I've tried moving the .bib files to other places, but TeXShop still can't find them. Where should I place the files - or how do I tell TeXShop how to find them.

Cheers

Will

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, the most obvious solution would be to place your `.bib` files in `~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib` again.

If you really want to keep your `bib` files in the `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/bibtex/bib` directory, the fact that they are not recognized suggests me you have probably forgotten to update your filename database: enter

`sudo mktexlsr`

in the Terminal, and then your admin password. After that it should work fine.

Comment: This worked (although in fact I used texhash). Sorry, didn't mention in my question that I had tried putting the files in ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib but that didn't help.

Comment: @Will Since `texhash`is in fact a symlink to `mktexlsr`, they mean the same thing ;-)

Comment: And it's strange that putting them in ~/Library/texmf/bibtex/bib does not work, they should be recognized straight away, without filename database update… If you indeed updated to Yosemite and did not install it from scratch (clean install), maybe it would be safer to completely reinstall MacTeX, to avoid things of the same sort happening. That's what I usually do by each update of the system.

Comment: @Will What do you get when you run `kpsewhich -var-value TEXMFHOME`? I've encountered a Mac where the `TEXMFHOME` value was somehow set to `~/texmf` rather than `~/Library/texmf`. It seems you've found a working solution, but I just thought I would mention this.